# Tool to check code for tables

Tags: tables, floats

MacTex ships a great tool called Latexit. Before compiling a document that contains an equation, the tool lets you compile the just the equation to check for errors. Very handy when you have a long or weird equation.

Curious to know if any such tool exists for checking float environments like tables. Personally, debugging tables is time consuming. Any tool that would enable me to debug a table separately from a document would be a massive help.

Comment: LaTeXIt works for more than just equations, doesn't it? I thought that's what I used to do the font samples for the TeX on Mac wiki.  Failing that, some editors will let you preview a small part of your document, separate from the rest., or you can use `standalone` as a class while working on the table and then include the document with the `standalone` package when its finalised. (This is how I often do diagrams, for example.)

Comment: O.o I'm an idiot - Latexit totally does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it is not testing, I normally do that with the `standalone` class, as suggested by cfr. I mainly use LaTeXit to typset standalone parts, like equations or tikz pictures. Then they can be saved as either pdf or png and included wherever you like, e.g. Power Point. In the preferences you can define your templets, both for preamble and for environments. Below is an example for a `tabularx` table.

[image]